# MongoDB custom sort order for a query with pagination

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have some documents in a MongoDB collection with this schema:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c1e8e318afd80016ce58b1"
    },
    "searchPriority": 1,
    "isLive": false,
    "vehicleCondition": "USED",
    "vehicleDetails": {
        "city": "Delhi"
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c1f2f418afd80016ce58b5"
    },
    "searchPriority": 2,
    "isLive": false,
    "vehicleCondition": "USED",
    "vehicleDetails": {
        "city": "Delhi"
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60cb429eadd33c00139d2be7"
    },
    "searchPriority": 1,
    "isLive": false,
    "vehicleCondition": "USED",
    "vehicleDetails": {
        "city": "Gurugram"
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c21be618afd80016ce5905"
    },
    "searchPriority": 2,
    "isLive": false,
    "vehicleCondition": "USED",
    "vehicleDetails": {
        "city": "New Delhi"
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60e306d29e452d00134b978f"
    },
    "searchPriority": 3,
    "isLive": false,
    "vehicleCondition": "USED",
    "vehicleDetails": {
        "city": "New Delhi"
    }
}
```

`vehicleCondition` can be `NEW` or `USED`, `isLive` can be `true` or `false` and `searchPriority` will be an integer between 1 to 3. (lower number means it should be higher in search result)

Here, except `_id` none of the other fields are unique. I have created a compound index on  `isLive`, `vehicleDetails.city` and `searchPriority`.

In my application I will perform some queries of this form:

- find all cars where `isLive` is `true`, `vehicleDetails.city` is
  either `Delhi` or `New Delhi` or `Gurugram` and `vehicleCondition` is
  `USED` (or `NEW`).

For this, I can do a find query like this:

```
db.collection.find({"isLive": true, "vehicleDetails.city": { $in: [ "Gurugram", "Delhi", "New Delhi" ] }, "vehicleCondition": "USED" }, {})
```

I want the results of this query sorted in this order:

- All cars belonging to the 1st city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 1st city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having  2nd lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 1st city inside `$in` arrray in the find
  query, having 3rd lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 2nd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 2nd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having 2nd lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 2nd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having 3rd lowest priority
  All cars belonging to the 3rd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 3rd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having 2nd lowest priority
- All cars belonging to the 3rd city inside `$in` arrray in the find query, having 3rd lowest priority

How can I do this? Since the number of documents returned by this query could be very large, I will be using pagination to limit the number of returned documents. Will this extra requirement have any effect on the possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot perform custom sort order easily. You can manipulate your document with MongoDB aggregation to perform custom order, but MongoDB cannot use indexes in that case. The best solution is: store preboiled order and use it for sorting.

Comment: @Valijon Can you please explain what "store preboiled order and use it for sorting" means?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't matter the order of `inside $in arrray` and you define the order static way: `Gurugram` is alwais the lowest (10X), then `Delhi` (20X), etc... Check this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8zTHzlLYiqD

Comment: @Valijon Thanks for answering but unfortunately having static priorities will not work for me because the `$in` array will vary depending on the context. For eg: it can be ["New Delhi", "Gurugram", "Delhi"] also in some cases and in that case I would want results from "New Delhi" to be on top. 

I have 0 experience in SQL DBs, do you think something like this would be possible in SQL?

Comment: Nope. The order that you provide it is used only for searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've read the other answer ( which gives a technical solution ) however based on your comments and request it is not suitable.

So firstly using `aggregate` here while technically solves the problem has some issues.

As you mentioned the query can have a high amount of documents matching, the aggregation pipeline unlike the `find` method does indeed load ALL of them into memory, this will inventively cause performance issue's, I also saw you mention something about not having an index. this will cause a "collection" scan for every single API call.

What I recommend you do is:

1. First you absolutely must build a compound index on `isLive, vehicleCondition, "vehicleDetails.city"` in case you don't have one. this is simply a must for high scale usage.
2. Now that we got that out of the way I recommend you split your call into into several pieces, I'm going to paste some puesdo code that might look a little all over the places but I do believe this is the best approach you can achieve using Mongo as each of these queries is suppose to be efficient by using the previously built index.

I will briefly explain the methodology, We want to be able to query each city independently of the other cities so we can use the "custom sort" function without needing to load all the matches into memory.

To do so we need to know how much each city needs to "skip" and "limit", as city #2 (Delhi) limit for example will be ( limit - city#1 (Gurugram) matches ).

So here is the pseudo code, I left it simple on purpose so it will be understandable. I will however add some ideas at the end for some basic improvements.

```
let limit = 10; // determined by req?
const skip = 0; // determined by req?
const cities = ['Gurugram', 'Delhi', 'New Delhi'];

// we need this to resolve the proper skip / limit. the last city is not relevant.
const countPromises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cities.length - 1; i++) {
    countPromises.push(db.collection.countDocuments({
        'isLive': true,
        'vehicleDetails.city': cities[i],
        'vehicleCondition': 'USED',
    }));
}
await Promise.all(countPromises);

// first city initial skip
const citySkips = [skip];

for (let i = 0; i < countPromises.length - 1; i++) {
    // if we have x results in the first city then we need to skip-x skipping for the next city.
    citySkips.push(Math.max(skip - countPromises[0], 0));
}

let finalResults = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    // assuming we skip over ALL city i results.
    if (citySkips[i] >= countPromises[i]) {
        continue;
    }
    const cityLimit = limit - finalResults.length;
    if (cityLimit <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    const cityResults = await db.collection.find({
        'isLive': true,
        'vehicleDetails.city': cities[i],
        'vehicleCondition': 'USED',
    }).sort({ sortPriority: 1 }).skip(citySkips[i]).limit(cityLimit);
    finalResults = finalResults.concat(cityResults);
}
```

Ok so possible improvements you can make:

- If the database doesn't get updated too often / you don't care about extreme accurateness you can pre-calculate each city match count in advance ( once a day? once a week? depending on your app ). This will speed up the `countDocuments` part which is needed to determine the `skip` and `limit` of each of the cities.
- The last `for` loop can be a `Promise.all` similar to the count to speed up results. Again if the number of cities if never too too high this could be a good solution.
- Lastly it wasn't clear if a single vehicle can be related to more than 1 city, but if it is the case then you need to add an exclude condition on documents that are already matched.

Comment: I dont really understand your code but after I posted this question I got an idea that I can query individual cities in the order I want. Eg: If I want results from Gurugram first, followed by Delhi and then New Delhi, I will start by querying Gurugram, then once Ihave all the results for Gurugram, I will start querying Delhi and then finally New Delhi. This way I dont have to rely on aggregate queries and I can also use the indexes on `isLive`, `vehicleCondition` and `vehicleDetails.city`. So all the queries will be fast. I think you have described the same idea.

Comment: Yes this is what i tried to convey, the code just pre-calculates the needed `skip` and `limit` values ahead of time so you can do the actual fetching concurrently ( which is the "slowest" part of the function ), however there is no problem in just doing it 1 by 1. I feel this is the best approach

Comment: I had some details in this question and without those this is the best answer. But based on my current requirements I have decided to go ahead with a different solution for now. I will be using Geo Spatial queries for this. I have posted a new question which is related to this. Can you please have a look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom sort order field after the match to sort the fields based on the input city criteria order and search priority order. Since it is calculated field index will not be used for sorting.

You can add pagination at the end just you would for any other query.

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "isLive": true,
      "vehicleDetails.city": {
        $in: [
          "Gurugram",
          "Delhi",
          "New Delhi"
        ]
      },
      "vehicleCondition": "USED"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "cityIndex": {
        "$indexOfArray": [
          [
            "Gurugram",
            "Delhi",
            "New Delhi"
          ],
          "$vehicleDetails.city"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      cityIndex: 1,
      sortPriority: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      cityIndex: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working example can be found here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/16-YOkPotLX

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer some more questions (have never used aggregate queries). How will this aggregate query work? Will it first fetch all the matching documents in the main memory, then sort them and then return the required `X`documents everytime I do `.limit(X)`? While this sorting is being done, is the entire DB or the particular collection being used blocked for other read/write operations? 

Since this query will be part of a web API which will be used very frequently is there a way to make this faster? Since its not using indexes, it will do a ful collection scan everytime?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes. No - concurrent access is allowed. I cant think of anything to make it faster. This is the best you can get for your use case.  As long as your working set is same it will not do a collection scan.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would work for you

```
 let x = ["Gurugram","Delhi", "New Delhi"];

db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "isLive": true,
                "vehicleDetails.city": {
                    $in: x
                },
                "vehicleCondition": "USED"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "_id": 1,
                "searchPriority": 1,
                "isLive": 1,
                "vehicleCondition": 1,
                "vehicleDetails": 1,
                index: { $indexOfArray: [x, "$vehicleDetails.city"] },
            }
        },
        { $sort: { index: 1, searchPriority: 1 } },
        {
            $project: {
                "index": 0,
            }
        }
    ]).toArray();
```

Comment: This will perform a blocking sort and will exceed 100MB limit for aggregate queries. If I do enable the option to allow disk usage, the queries will be very very slow. Also, I am not sure how this will work with pagination. Where do I put the `limit` and `skip`clauses? Will it perform the sorting each time I call it with a different `skip` value for pagination?

Comment: `{$project: {"index": 0, } }, {$limit :100},   { $skip : 5 } ]).toArray(); `

Comment: Will it not perform `match`, `project`, 'sort' everytime I use this query?

Comment: It will. when a query is executed the pipeline queries will get executed. If you dont want mongodb to be accessed every time, then, set a find query to get all documents and then use filter function in JS to filter out the required. But this takes more time than querying